# Why Nextjs reloads page when i go to not-found page

Tags: redirect, next.js, browser

Why when i call this:

```js
...
router.push('/some-not-existing-page');
...
```

Nextjs reloads page instead of just rendering it. When i redirecting to existing page it works as expected.

I'm new in nextjs, sorry for dumb question..